# Limit user to a range of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm trying to write some code that does some unit conversions and prints them in a for loop. I want to limit the user to values in a range [1e5, 1e6]. I'm trying to incorporate this limit into a user-defined function for the inputs a and b as seen in the code. Here's the full code:

```
import numpy as np # library needed for arange function to allow floats in for
                                                               # loop range

#------------------------------ColorText-------------------------------------#
def ColorText(text, color): # will use red as colour for results title headings
    CEND = '\033[0m'
    CBOLD = '\033[1m'
    CBLACK = '\033[0m'
    CRED = '\033[31m'
    if color == 'red' :
        return CRED + CBOLD + text + CEND
    else:
        return CBLACK + text + CEND
#---------------------------end ColorText------------------------------------#

#---------------------------Handling exceptions------------------------------#
# sets the limits on values a and b and prevents users from typing in letters
def inputNumber_a():
    """
    This is the user defined function for the first value (a). It incorporates
    a while loop to keep asking the user for new values of a (until an 
    acceptable value is given) within a specified range and prevents the user 
    from typing in letters instead of numbers without aborting the entire 
    program. A similar function is seen below for value b.
    """
    while True:
        try:
            userInput = float(input('Please enter the value for a in kWh \
(1e5 <= a <= 1e6) (e.g. 1.5e5): '))
            while (userInput < 100000) and (userInput > 1000000):
                print('\aThis value for a is outside the program limits! \
Please try again.')
                userInput = float(input('Please enter the value for a in \
kWh (1e5 <= a <= 1e6): '))
        except ValueError:
            print('\aYou did not enter a valid number! Please try again.')
            continue
        else:
            return userInput

def inputNumber_b():
    while True:
        try:
            userInput = float(input('Please enter the value for b in kWh \
(1e5 <= a <= 1e6): '))
            while (userInput < 1e5) and (userInput > 1e6):
                print('\aThis value for b is outside the program limits! \
Please try again.')
                userInput = float(input('Please enter the value for b in \
kWh (1e5 <= a <= 1e6): '))
        except ValueError:
            print('\aYou did not enter a valid number! Please try again.')
            continue
        else:
            return userInput
#----------------------------end Handling Exceptions-------------------------#

#----------------------------User defined functions--------------------------#
def joules(num):
    """
    

    Parameters
    ----------
    num : Value in kWh given by the user.

    Returns
    -------
    Value in energy Joules (E(J)). The conversion factor states that 1kWh is 
    equal to 3.6e6 Joules. Reference: 
    https://www.calculatorology.com/kwh-to-joules-conversion/
    [float]

    """
    return num * (3.6e6)

def calories(num):
    """
    

    Parameters
    ----------
    num : Value in kWh (kilowatt-hours) given by the user.

    Returns
    -------
    Value in energy calories (E(cal)), scientific calories that is. Note that 
    calories increase with temperature so this conversion factor is at temper-
    ature = 0 centigrade. Note: Kilowatt hour is a metric unit of energy.  
    Calorie is a pre-SI metric unit of energy. States that 
    1kWh = 859845.228cal. Reference: 
    https://www.aqua-calc.com/convert/energy/kilowatt-hour-to-calorie
    
    """
    return num * 859845.228
#---------------------------end User defined functions-----------------------#

#---------------------------Main program starts here-------------------------#

# inform the user what is happening
print('\nThis program converts kilowatt-hours (kWh) to Joules (J) and \
Calories (cal) within a range given by the user.')
print('[minimum value = 1e5, maximum value = 1e6, step rate = 1e5]')


ans = 'y'
while True:
    if ans == 'y':
        
        a = inputNumber_a()
        b = inputNumber_b()
        
        colour = 'red'
        print(ColorText('\n{0:f>20}'.format('kWh'), colour),
              ColorText('{0:^5}'.format('|'), colour),
              ColorText('{0:f>20}'.format('Joules'), colour),
              ColorText('{0:^5}'.format('|'), colour),
              ColorText('{0:f>20}'.format('Calories'), colour))
            
        for i in np.arange(0, b, 100000):
            n = a + i
            joule = joules(n)
            cal = calories(n)
            
            
            print('{0:f>20.4e}'.format(n),
                  '{0:^5}'.format('|'),
                  '{0:f>20.4e}'.format(joule),
                  '{0:^5}'.format('|'),
                  '{0:f>20.4e}'.format(cal))
        
        ans = input('\nWould you like to set another range of values? (y/n): ')
    else:
        break
```

At the moment the program runs no matter what value I put in for a and b. It only deals with the exception when the user types in a letter so far. Help would be greatly appreciated. It would be optimal if I could set the input range limits in the `inputNumber_a()` and `inputNumber_b()` functions in the 'Handling Exceptions' part of the code. Thank you.

Comment: `while (userInput < 100000) and (userInput > 1000000)`...it's not possible for a value to be both _less than_ 100000 `and` _greater than_ 1000000, should that be `or`?

Comment: @G.Anderson Wow thank you. I've actually made this mistake before by putting ``and`` instead of ``or`` into my code. I kept overlooking this one tiny thing. I fixed it and code runs fine now so thanks!